# VB.Net CheckBoxes. Need to populate from a database and also help in designing

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, checkbox

I have this requirement and, since I'm new to VB.Net, don't really have much of an idea how to do this. I have 20 CheckBoxes with associated dropdowns and TextBoxes for each. The example is:

```
table
  tr
   td
    checkbox -- textbox -- dropdownlist
   /td
  /tr
  tr
   td
    chk1        txtbox1    ddl1
   /td
  /tr
  tr
   td
    chk2        txtbox2    ddl2
   /td
  /tr
.
.
.
```

and so on. The above structure shall be in one row of a table. Does anyone know how to design this code using a recursive loop, and also how to take the CheckBox data and send it to a database table for records insertion, updating and selection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CheckBoxList and bind it to your data.

[Here is an example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/ADO.net-Database/BinddatasourcetoaspCheckBoxList.htm)

[Here is another example](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=859)

[And here is an example](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webforms/controls/settinglayoutincheckboxlist.aspx) on how to lay out the CheckboxList

EDIT:
OK.  [Another example](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/66/Referencing-CheckBoxes-in-GridView-Repeater-and-DataList-controls) on using a Checkbox inside a repeater.

Comment: @reder "none of the examples given by rockinthe... work".  using DataBind to bind your data to a CheckBoxList is a good way of doing it.  Can you post some code of what you tried?

Comment: Ah... @Heinzi 's edit of the original question adds clarification.  Why don't you try putting in an asp:repeater for your layout?